# Automatically add country code to phone field

Tags: web2lead

I am quite new to Salesforce and wondering if such a thing is possible. Salesforce fails to pick up duplicates on phone numbers as sometimes leads are created with, for example: +44012345 or 004412345 or 12345.

Is there a way to make it, so that depending on the country they select on the Web2Lead form, it will automatically put the code in front of the phone number?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest doing what you plan to do and trying to solve this with just client-side code on the web2lead form. But, if you really want to, you can. Just pick some validation library that you like the look of install it on the web2lead form. SF will not interfere with that at all.

However, just putting a country code in front of what the user typed wouldn't be a terribly robust solution. By itself, it wouldn't stop users from ignoring the fact that you're going to put +44 on there and putting another +44 on.

And it wouldn't help with data that came from anywhere other than that web2lead form.

Normally, I'd use the approach of reducing the phone number information into a "normal form" i.e. have one field for the phone number as the user typed it, and another field for the normalised version where we control what it looks like.

So, you might decide your normal form starts with a +, followed by the country code, followed by the whole number with no spaces. "Just" write a trigger that turns all of your above examples into the normal form. Then, you can use simple/stupid duplicate matching rules that only compare the normal form.